# Download file error [com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 401 Unauthorized]

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I am using following code in my Android code, from here https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get

Everthing is ok, the file.getDownloadUrl() is not null, and is a really long URL.

But I am getting error 401 when getting the HttpResponse resp.

What is the problem?

I assume I am already authorized because I can list all my files in my GoogleDrive, get the fileId and even the file.getDownloadUrl(). My OAuth2.0 scope is DRIVE.

```
11-26 06:40:37.614: W/System.err(15750): com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 401 Unauthorized
11-26 06:40:37.614: W/System.err(15750):    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1062)
```

CODE:

```
  /**
       * Download a file's content.
       *
       * @param service Drive API service instance.
       * @param file Drive File instance.
       * @return InputStream containing the file's content if successful,
       *         {@code null} otherwise.
       */
      private static InputStream downloadFile(Drive service, File file) {
        if (file.getDownloadUrl() != null && file.getDownloadUrl().length() > 0) {
          try {
            HttpResponse resp =
                service.getRequestFactory().buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(file.getDownloadUrl()))
                    .execute();  //--ERROR HERE--
            return resp.getContent();
          } catch (IOException e) {
            // An error occurred.
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
          }
        } else {
          // The file doesn't have any content stored on Drive.
          return null;
        }
      }
```

LogCat:

```
11-26 06:50:04.638: I/fileId(16350): 0B2PmmdZsG0kJUTFNcWNaam9KLVE

11-26 06:50:07.896: I/file.getDownloadUrl()(16350): https://doc-0s-8g-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/3l0k423jsgncap9ihfdfv9kb388vqac9/glhd2gbkatjpv4cb60383pc8b127o0l2/1353873600000/11834093636053924840/11834093636053924840/0B2PmmdZsG0kJUTFNcWNaam9KLVE?h=16653014193614665626&e=download&gd=true
```

Comment: Don't know the details of the Drive API, but generally you have to pass the token in every request. Does it specifically say that you don't need it when downloading files?

Comment: The web page you linked has an 'authorize request' toggle, so it looks like it may be needed. Should look something like this: `Authorization:  Bearer ya29.AHES6...`

Comment: Ya you are right, I added headers.setAuthorization("Bearer " + "xxx") and it works now. Thanks!

Comment: OK, glad it works for you. Added below as an answer.

Comment: Could you be so kind and write to me how did you add to your code headers.setAuthorization("Bearer " + "xxx") ? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the parameter `service` is the instance of `Drive` you have authorized. If it's not the case, `buildGetRequest` can't add the authorization header because it does not know it

Comment: I am quite sure that the service, which is the instance of Drive I have authorized. Because I set in as public static in another class. (I know this is a bad practice)

Anyway, do you mean that if the Drive instance is correct, then we do not need to specifically set header (Authorization: Bearer xxxx) everytime?

Right now I have temporary solved it by adding header everytime i build request as commented by Nikolay Elenkov above.

Comment: The `RequestFactory` should be responsible for adding that header, yes. At least it does in with the last version of the Java API. When you built the `Drive` object, you set the `Credentials` ?

Comment: Thanks for your help! I was using http://one-dollar.us/DriveActivity.java by Stephen Wylie, somehow when he build the Drive object, he passed "null" at the HttpRequestInitializer.
I have added the HttpRequestFactory.getInitializer when building the Drive object, and it is working great now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your OAuth 2.0 token to an authorization header for this to work. Should look something like this: `Authorization: Bearer ya29.AHES6...`.

Comment: Ok, you are right, as we can see here: 

Once you have fetched the URL, you can use it to download the file content by making an authorized GET request to it. For example:

GET https://doc-04-c1-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/ivearmirmg66&e=download&gd=true
Authorization: Bearer ya29.AHESVbXTUv5mHMo3RYfmS1YJonjzzdTOFZwvyOAUVhrs

But how?